# Swift. macOS. Record sound from speakers

Tags: swift, macos, audio, recording, avcapturedevice

I want to make the macOS-app for recording the audio from system and other apps (music, video, etc).
Not microphone.
How can I make that? I see only options the recording from microphone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean to record the system-out sound (other apps, music, etc.).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It definitely is. See Loopback, and Audio Hijack by https://rogueamoeba.com/ , and also SoundFlower

Comment: Well then I was wrong apparently so then OP has some research to do.